# How to crawl and display the details of a url?

Tags: php, html, regex, curl

i am currently having problem displaying the image and price of a url from flipkart, what i want is to display the product image and price of a url and continuously crawl all the url's following it and display the details for the same in one page, but i get the error saying redirection limit reached, failed to open stream.

here is my code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 4000);
$to_crawl = "http://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6/p/itme5rf6ewg7trwz?pid=MOBEYGPZAHZQMCKZ&otracker=from-search&srno=t_4&query=apple&al=hplRX0gsd%2BUs3897GU7MA33GdyuXyA9x5heu%2FXnCd8gCFiEqsIXwVoaLq2lx4bRfFLwHQxVDMNU%3D&ref=cfd05202-e814-4bb4-bbe2-422b4ecc6df9";
$c = array();
function getPriceFromFlipkart($url) {

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<meta itemprop="price" content="([^"]*)"/';
preg_match($regex, $html, $price);

$regex = '/<h1[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/h1>/';
preg_match($regex, $html, $title);

$regex = '/data-src="([^"]*)"/i';
preg_match($regex, $html, $image);
}
function get_links($url){
    global $c;
    $input = file_get_contents($url);
    $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
    preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches);
    $base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $l = $matches[2];
    foreach($l as $link) {
        if(strpos($link, "#")) {
            $link = substr($link,0, strpos($link, "#"));
        }
        if(substr($link,0,1) == ".") {
            $link = substr($link, 1);
        }
        if(substr($link,0,7)=="http://") {
            $link = $link;
        }
        else if(substr($link,0,8) =="https://") {
            $link = $link;
        }
        else if(substr($link,0,2) =="//") {
            $link = substr($link, 2);
        }
        else if(substr($link,0,2) =="#") {
            $link = $url;
        }
        else if(substr($link,0,2) =="mailto:") {
            $link = "[".$link."]";
        }
        else {
            if(substr($link,0,1) != "/") {
            $link = $base_url."/".$link;
        }
        else {
            $link = $base_url.$link;
        }
        }
        if(substr($link, 0, 7)=="http://" && substr($link, 0, 8)!="https://" && substr($link, 0, 1)=="[") {
            if(substr($url, 0, 8) == "https://") {
                $link = "https://".$link;
            }
            else {
                $link = "http://".$link;
            }
        }
        //echo $link."<br />";
        if(!in_array($link,$c)) {
            array_push($c,$link);
        }
    }
}
get_links($to_crawl);
foreach ($c as $page) {
    get_links($page);
}
foreach ($c as $page) {
    $response = getPriceFromFlipkart($page);

echo json_encode($response);
    echo $page."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: http://htmlparsing.com/php.html this is a guide on how to use the DOM module for parsing html. Use this to get the `<a>` tags.

Comment: how can i parse this : '$regex = '/<meta itemprop="price" content="([^"]*)"/';
preg_match($regex, $html, $price);  using DOM.

Comment: You're supposed to use the DOM parser on the page you get back from curl.